# Gridview: Many controls in same row cell

Tags: c#, gridview

I have many controls in same gridview cell. I am using the following code. But i want them to be displayed vertically instead of horizontally, because with the following code it assigns them in the same line. Any help?

```
RadioButton rd1 = new RadioButton();
rd1.Text = "Test1";
RadioButton rd2 = new RadioButton();
rd2.Text = "Test2";
grdRSM.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls.Add(rd1);
grdRSM.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls.Add(rd2);
```

Comment: What you required is not clear. pls give more details

Comment: With the  above code it add my radiobuttons in the same cell and same 'line'. But i want the radiobuttons to appear in different 'line'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do two thing

**First**

Use `RadioButtonList` instead of single `RadioButton` and set it's `RepeatDirection="Vertical"`

**Second**

Use `HtmlGenericControl` to render a `BR` something like this

```
RadioButton rd1 = new RadioButton();
rd1.Text = "Test1";
RadioButton rd2 = new RadioButton();
rd2.Text = "Test2";

HtmlGenericControl br = new HtmlGenericControl("BR");

grdRSM.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls.Add(rd1);
grdRSM.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls.Add(br);
grdRSM.Rows[0].Cells[2].Controls.Add(rd2);
```

It would make those `RadioButtons` to be rendered vertically

Answer (score 0):

From different line, you meant different rows??. Then please try this by replacing your last line of code.

```
 grdRSM.Rows[1].Cells[2].Controls.Add(rd2);
```